# "Early critics of Emily Dickinson's poetry mistook for simple-mindedness the surface of artlessness..."

Tags: sentence

I didn't get what "mistook for simple-mindedness the surface of artlessness" means.

Usually, we'd say that you mistook the brown candy for the blue one. Meaning that you actually wanted (or expected) the blue candy but instead (may be mistakenly) picked the brown (wrong) one.

Applying the same analogy here, does it mean that the critics (wrongly) interpreted artlessness as simple-mindedness?

Here is the complete sentence as it appeared in a reference material for an exam prep:

> "Early critics of Emily Dickinson's poetry mistook for simple-mindedness the surface of artlessness that in fact she constructed with such ___."

Now depending on the (correct) interpretation of the sentence, I would construe a positive or negative word for the blank. Example, the poet's work was good or naive.

Comment: Look up the definition of *artlessness*. Look up the definition of "mistook". I don't think you understand what they mean. We're not here to look up words for you.

Comment: I did, it means 'being naive'. Did I misquote something? Please excuse me if I wasn't able to make my doubt clear. Will appreciate any suggestion to improve if something is wrong.

Comment: *artlessness* does ***not*** mean 'being naive' here, and neither does *mistook*.

Comment: @PeterShor: "I don't think you understand what they mean." - you are right. That is the reason i'm here. 

"We're not here to look up words for you." - and I don't even want you to but instead of sarcasm, I will welcome constructive criticism (or suggestion). 

I'm not testing your (or the community's) knowledge rather seeking to clarify my doubt. I don't know what is wrong with the post. Really!

Comment: Actually, I see that the proper definition of 'artlessness' here is really not found in that many dictionaries, so maybe this is a reasonable question. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/artless) says **artless**: "Without effort or pretentiousness; natural and simple:
*an artless literary masterpiece*". Although I'd say "the appearance of effort" and not "effort".

Comment: "does it mean that the critics (wrongly) interpreted artlessness as simple-mindedness?"  Almost.  The original said "surface of artlessness", not "artlessness" per se, meaning that the *first impression* of her poetry apt to be is one of artless simplicity (while beneath that "surface" lies considerable depth and complexity).

Comment: I don't get why this question is downvoted!!

Comment: the question is downvoted because it's silly.  it's a **completely straightforward sentence**, it's just that one needs to know what "artless" means ("effortless -looking").  that's all "artless" means, it's that simple.

Comment: footnote: "artless" is one of those annoying words in English, where, if you're a new English speaker, you'd **assume** the word means a certain thing, but it fact it has utterly no connection to that.  artless just means "effortless looking".  for example, jeans and a tshirt are "artless" .. a big wedding dress is certainly not.

Comment: That clearly contradicts the fact that Peter Shor invested so much time and effort in bringing to light. Did you read his comments @JoeBlow?

Comment: "the question is downvoted because it's silly. it's a completely straightforward sentence". I don't think that the other community members also feel the same. 

Btw, is that the kind of attitude that we are to expect on Stack Exchange? @JoeBlow

Comment: @Vaibhav: it wasn't that much time and effort. I just looked in two online dictionaries, until I found one that gave the correct meaning. I'm really surprised that [not all of them](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artless) listed this meaning.

Comment: @Vaibhav: as I implied in my first comment, questions which you can answer by looking up words in any dictionary are not on-topic here. And if the right definition of *artless* was in all good dictionaries, as it should be, this question would clearly be off-topic. I expect the downvoters didn't realize that the correct  meaning of *artless* was not that easy to find.

Comment: @PeterShor: So what do you suggest I should have done? After consulting the dictionary (which has always provided me the correct definitions, this being an exception, probably) and investing commensurate time in trying to decipher the connotation of the words, should have simply left it and not posted here? Honestly, I don't think I agree with your 'on/off-topic' argument in the last comment. I did the research to find a solution that I could and shared my interpretation and findings clearly.

Comment: @Vaibhav: there's not much you could have done. It's the unfortunate omission of this meaning of *artless* from dictionaries which resulted in the downvotes.

Comment: @HotLicks: Your (upvoted) comment best addresses and resolves my doubt. You might want to put that as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*does it mean that the critics (wrongly) interpreted artlessness as simple-mindedness?*

Almost. The original said "surface of artlessness", not "artlessness" per se, meaning that the first impression of her poetry is apt to be is one of artless simplicity (while beneath that "surface" lies considerable depth and complexity).

Answer (score 4):

> Now depending on the (correct) interpretation of the sentence, I would construe a positive or negative word for the blank. Example, the poet's work was good or naive.

They are clearly looking for a positive response there, something like *care* or *craft* or *skill*–anything that shows Dickinson as someone with great artistic power.

Even if you didn't understand the comparison with its inversion of word order, you would have to notice the "in fact" in the exam prep sentence, which is a "turnaround" expression that is a counter to what has previously been stated. Let's break it down into a simpler expression:

> X says Y is Z when **in fact** _________.

Without knowing the first thing about What X, Y and Z mean, you should still be able to infer something about the desired answer simply by noticing that "contrary" flag. You could at least with confidence fill in the blank with a statement like "Y is a value other than Z."

Be careful, though, that the "in fact" is itself set up by some other contrary indicator like *but* or *although* or *when*. If it's set off by *and* or another reinforcing word it could be construed as an affirimation:

> X says Y is Z **and in fact** ____________.

Here you would have to answer to the effect that Y is indeed Z.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and insightful response. Also appreciate the contrast and suggestions.

Actually, I did have a little issue initially in understanding what the critics mistook however, was quickly able to figure that one out, as mentioned in the analogy in the post. What actually got me confounded was the connotation of the word 'artlessness'. Even the dictionary read: "The quality of innocent naiveté".
Synonyms: ingenuousness, innocent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking, and I agree. The statement should be inverted:

"Early critics of Emily Dickinson's poetry mistook the surface of artlessness for simple-mindedness..."

In this way, the meaning is clearer. However, the *for* in "mistook *for* simple-mindedness," does convey the intended meaning - despite being a bit awkward.

Comment: If it were just _surface of artlessness_ on its own, I would have advised inverting the order, too; but there's an embedded clause in that constituent, too, which actually makes the order given less awkward to me. “[They] mistook the surface of artlessness that in fact she constructed with such [carefully crafted uses of … _vel sim_] for simple-mindedness” is far clunkier to read.

Comment: quite right, Janus

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You'd split it up with 2 hyphens, or into 2 sentences.  I agree with oldbag the sentence from the exam prep is not a very good one.

Answer (score -1):

It couldn't be simpler:

a "surface of artlessness" ...

you know what "artlessness" means right.  it means "achieved without effort"... "natural" .. "simple"

so the poetry has an "artless" surface:  ie, it appears to have been made without effort.

However! In fact, ED achieved that "effortless" feel, with tremendous effort and skill.

As it says: "the surface of artlessness that in fact she constructed with such [effort]"

She "makes it look easy" but in fact it was "a huge effort, carefully constructed".

So the sentence is simply saying:  early critics foolishly thought she was just naive, silly, because the poems have an "effortless" feel.  But in fact, she put a huge effort in to creating that "effortless" feel.

It's an extremely straightforward sentence: nothing should be inverted, there are no typos etc.

As long as you know that "artless" means "effortless-looking", it's very straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

Original sentence from exam:
*Early critics of Emily Dickinson’s poetry mistook for simple-mindedness the surface of artlessness that in fact she constructed with such* **BLANK**.
*Possible answers: B. craft, C. cunning*

According to several sources and common conventional meaning we can agree upon, "**simple-minded**" means "**having or showing very little intelligence or judgment**".

According to Dictionary.com, and to a direct root analysis of the adjective "artless" as compound word, **artless** (**art** - **less** (**less**: without, lacking of)) means lacking art, knowledge, or skill.

Hence, my understanding is that the sentence being scrutinized states that those "... early critics mistook" Emily Dickinson's poetry as "something of very little intelligence", due to the cover of "lacking of art, knowledge or skill" she tarnished her poems with, whereas in fact they were constructed with such craft...

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer "apparent simplicity" or "simplicity at first glance" to "surface of artlessness". Sometimes simplicity is on a higher artistic level than aristry. We have a lot of artistic poems and no-one knows what the poet is talking about.